# How to responsively align items with Flexbox in CSS3?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using CSS3 flexbox. I have 2 texts next to each other inside a div.

I want **Text A** to be aligned on the **left** side and **Text B** on the **right side**, generally.

However if **Text B** can't fit on one line, I want it to be **left** aligned on the next row.

Here is my attempt, the issue is that **Text B** goes to the right side if there's not enough space:

```css
.main { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.b { margin-left: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <a class="a" href="#">This is some text for the LEFT side.</a>
    <a class="b" href="#">This is some text for the RIGHT side IF it fits the screen. Left otherwise.</a>
</div>
```

How can we do this with Flexbox using CSS3 only?

Comment: use margin-right:auto on text A instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `margin-left: auto` from the b class and add the `justify-content:space-between` inside the main class for distributing the items evenly so the first item is flush with the start and the last is flush with the end.

```css
.main { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content:space-between}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <a class="a" href="#">This is some text for the LEFT side.</a>
    <a class="b" href="#">This is some text for the RIGHT side IF it fits the screen. Left otherwise.</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <a class="a" href="#">This is some text for the LEFT side.</a>
    <a class="b" href="#">Short text - RIGHT side IF it fits the screen. Left otherwise.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `.main` class add , `justify-content:space-between;` to push the child elements apart